# Get hour:minutes from DATETIME2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, datetime2

I have a problem in SQL Server 2008 R2. I want to get `HH:mm` from a `DATETIME2` column. When I write this statement:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), getdate(), 8)
```

I am getting perfect result that is `11:19`, but when I try to get time from:

```
SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), '1900-01-01 01:10:00.0000000', 8))
```

I am getting result `1900` but I need `01:10`.

How can I get the result from this statement? I know there there are multiple questions/answers like this but I have not found any answer that matches my question.

Comment: you do realize that both statement are not equal. [1] is to convert datetime to string using style 8. [2] is to convert string to string using style 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On SQL Server side (in stored procedure, for example), you can use this kind of conversion:

```
declare @dt datetime2(0) = sysdatetime();

select @dt as [Date], left(convert(time(0), @dt, 108), 5) as [HH:mm];
```

If you need to display your data on the client side, such as a report or your app, it's better to use client' formatting capabilities. This way, you may be able to take such factors into account as preferred calendar system, 12- or 24-hour clock, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), 
DATEPART(HOUR, '1900-01-01 01:10:00.0000000')), 2) hh, 
DATEPART(minute, '1900-01-01 01:10:00.0000000') mm
```

Or

`SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(TIME(0), '1900-01-01 01:10:00.0000000'), 2) hh , DATEPART(minute, '1900-01-01 01:10:00.0000000') mm`

Comment: this is returning 1:10 from your query  but i want 01:10

Comment: thanks for your reply but Format support in 2012 sql server

Comment: check now, i am having 2012 its hard to tell from my side

Answer (score 0):

For many format of 24H datetime length is 19 so you can use the following

```
 SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, Substring('1900-01-01 01:10:00.0000000',1,19)) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':' + CAST(DATEPART(minute, substring('1900-01-01 01:10:00.0000000',1,19)) AS VARCHAR(2)) HHmm
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @H.Fadlaallah Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ':' to data type int

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think this is what you want.

this will give answer: 1:10

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CONVERT(DATETIME,'1900-01-01 01:10:00.000'),8)
```

You can also try this

```
select convert(VARCHAR,DATEPART(HOUR,'1900-01-01 01:10:00.0000000'))+':'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(MINUTE,'1900-01-01 01:10:00.0000000'))
```